# SUSE Linux Enterprise - Python3 error with readline in /etc/inputrc

Tags: python, suse, readline

When I start a python3 shell on my machine, I get the following warnings:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
readline: /etc/inputrc: line 18: term: unknown variable name
readline: /etc/inputrc: line 18: term: unknown variable name
```

I am using an Anaconda distribution. When using the default `python` executable, I do not get any warning.

The 18th line of `/etc/inputrc` is:

```
$ cat /etc/inputrc | sed -n 18p
set term xy
```

My system versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux tlelectra01 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

There is already a [bug report](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1012648) for this apparently, but without any indication on how to solve this...

How can I solve this? I only have user privileges on this machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like SuSE ships an /etc/inputrc that has this `set term` in it which doesn't seem to be a valid variable in readline, at least from the [documentation](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC10) and the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline), both of which list the existing variables and none of them lists "term" as a valid one...

The file `.inputrc` in your home directory overrides the global /etc/inputrc, when it exists. So one option is to copy `/etc/inputrc` into `~/.inputrc` for your user, then edit it and delete line 18. This should hopefully solve the issue.

If you already have a `~/.inputrc`, check if it has a `$include  /etc/inputrc` in it. In that case, replace that line with the contents of /etc/inputrc and delete the line that sets the invalid "term" variable. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I did a copy of `/etc/inputrc` to `~/.inputrc` and it worked. I had to start a new shell for the change to be taken into account though.

Comment: Do you think this can be fixed with a specific patch to readline on suse when building readline and python3 from source?

Comment: @Fanchi I don't know much about SuSE, but you can check the [source RPM for bash](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/2/search/bash-4.4-lp150.7.8.src.rpm) which seems to be where SuSE ships readline, and look inside to see what kind of patches they ship for it... (Note, URL for package came from search in pkgs.org, so not sure it's very accurate either.) Another option is for you to install RPM for readline-devel and compile your custom Python with it, instead of building readline from source yourself too. Good luck!